Mongodb upgrade
We are upgrading the mongo db. While running test cases in the pipeline, we are getting this error. Can anyone please advise. Locally(Window) its runs good.
Error creating bean with name 'embeddedMongoServer' defined in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration:
  Bean instantiation via factory method failed;
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException:
    Failed to instantiate [de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable]:
      Factory method 'embeddedMongoServer' threw exception;
      nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        could not resolve package for Version{4.4.16}:
          Platform{operatingSystem=Linux, architecture=X86_64

I have this in build.gradle:
testImplementation 'de.flapdoodle.embed:de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.spring27x:4.6.2'

and in application.yml:
mongodb.embedded.version: = 4.4.16

